# How to run a jar file in command line which is packaged in another jar file?

Tags: java, jar

In my java code, I run a jar file (named file1.jar) from the command line like this:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c java -jar file1.jar");
```

If I package the whole project into a jar file (named file2.jar), then the command is invalid because of path problems. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: why would you do that? why not just calling the entrypoint of that jar file in your java code, instead of triggering the jar?

Comment: The DUP question can tell you how to get to a path that should work. But I agree: what is the point of starting **another** JVM to run that piece of code? Do you actually understand all the consequences of doing so?